# Add Constraint Layout Barriers Missing In Context Menu of Android Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I am currently going through a ConstraintLayout tutorial and stuck in a specific step (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/#10).

The source is here (https://github.com/googlecodelabs/constraint-layout).

Per instructions below, it says to add a vertical barrier but I do not see the add option in the menu. Actually the entire menu options look different. Where is the "Add Vertical barrier" menu?

> Right click on ConstraintLayout in the blueprint or the Component
>   Tree. You will see the Add Vertical barrier and Add Horizontal barrier
>   options.

I am running Android 2.3.3.

build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.googleio"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1'
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am running Android 2.3.3.

I am going to guess that you mean that you are running Android Studio 2.3.3. In that case, there is no such menu. That is added in Android Studio 3.0, available in beta from today.

Comment: Yes it should be Android Studio 2.3.3. I will leave it as it to keep the answer consistent. Based on your answer, I decided just to add the component via XML edit. Thank you.

Comment: I later found we can install beta version along side stable version. This is the right approach as using Android Studio 3.0 is necessary to use the Vertical Barrier component.

Comment: I still do not see those barrier options, Android Studio v3.0 ConstraintLayout & ConstraintLayoutSolver 1.0.2

Comment: @VishnuPrabhu: You also need the beta(?) of `ConstraintLayout` 1.1, IIRC.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. AS V3.0.1 with ConstraintLayout 1.0.2. Yet no barrier option. Which beta version do I need?

Comment: @AbirHasan: The latest is `1.1.0-beta3`, according to https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

Comment: @CommonsWare : I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 and constraint-layout:1.0.2. Still the "Add (Vertical/Horizontal) Barrier" option is missing.

Comment: @MonishKamble: You also need the beta of `ConstraintLayout` 1.1. The current latest is `1.1.0-beta3`.

Comment: @CommonsWare : But as per https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-to-a-barrier, Barriers are available with constraint-layout:1.0.2.  Even [Android Studio 3.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html) says create barriers can be availed with an exception for _Add Group_, which requires  ConstraintLayout 1.1.0 beta 2 or higher

Comment: @MonishKamble: I have no idea why Android Studio behaves as it does, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your **gradle (Module:app)**

`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1'`