# Add (Vertical/Horizontal) Barriers missing in layout editor toolbar and context menu of Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I was referring a guide on using Constraint layout at   https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-to-a-barrier to get hands on with Barriers.

The step says,

> To create a barrier, follow these steps:
>
> Click Guidelines in the toolbar, and then click Add Vertical Barrier or Add >Horizontal Barrier.

Whereas when I clicked on Guidelines icon, it displayed only two options i.e.,

1. Add Vertical Guideline
2. Add Horizontal Guideline

Even the context menu does not display option to add Barrier.

---

Already there is a question with same context [Add Constratint Layout Barriers Missing In Context Menu of Android Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028235/add-constratint-layout-barriers-missing-in-context-menu-of-android-android-studi) but for Android Studio 2.3.3 which is answered by CommonsWare.

Had a discussion with CommonsWare through comments where he suggested to use ***beta of ConstraintLayout 1.1***.

But as per the [training guide](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project) for using ConstraintLayout the constraintLayout version is 1.0.2

> dependencies {
>      compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
>   }

*Even [**Android Studio 3.0 release notes**](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#layout-editor) says create barriers option is now supported (with an exception for Add Group, which requires ConstraintLayout 1.1.0 beta 2 or higher).*

[image: screenshot of Android Studio 3.0 release notes]

**Environment details :**

```
Android Studio 3.0.1
Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 8.1 6.3

Constraint Layout :1.0.2
Graddle wrapper : gradle-4.1
buildToolsVersion : 26.0.2
```

Answer (score 4):

Per [this documentation](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/05/constraintlayout-110-beta-1-release.html) barriers were introduced in version 1.1.0-beta1 of `ConstraintLayout`. (Emphasis is mine)

> Bugfixes related to wrap_content
>
> New features: **barriers**, placeholder, percent dimensions

Since barriers were introduced in 1.1.0-beta1, you will not see them in any earlier releases.

I am currently running Android Studio 3.0.1 with `ConstraintLayout` 1.1.0-beta3 and this is what I see when I press the guidelines button in the designer:

[image]

The context menu also shows barriers as an option.

So, in short, you need Android Studio 3.0+ and `ConstraintLayout` version 1.1.0-beta1 or later to see these options.